# Facets with default

Tags: search

Anybody know how to set a default facet value?

I have facets set up and working using facet_api blocks alongside a view in a panel.  Is there a (hopefully easy) way to set one of the facets have a value selected by default on an initial page render?

//fyi Drupal 7.

Thanks.

Comment: This facet on which field is created?

Answer (score 0):

If you using module Search API, you can use hook_search_api_solr_query_alter.

Try to add filter for your facet:

```
$call_args['params']['fq'][] = 'your_field:your_value';
```

It should help.
It's a short way to do this but you have to know a name of the field in the index.